# AngularJS ng repeat filter by one attribute in object and a text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have this issue and I would like to get ideas on how to solve it in the best approach. I need to filter ng-repeat results with a text box and when hashtag is being used as the first sign I need the filter to work only on one specific column. for example:

1. by default = filter only by text inserted in the search box - meaning
   the filter should work on all attributes of each user.
2. Filter by only one attribute when user enter Hashtag: value.
   For instance: (instead of regular value user insert in search box)

   ```
   #ID: 33
   ```

   will filter only users who have id which contains 33.

   ```
   #date: 1/12/2014
   ```

   wil filter only users who have the following date

```
var users = [{
  "name": "Bruce",
  "city": "Thailand",
  "date": "1/12/2014",
  "id": 3376848
}, {
  "name": "Frank",
  "city": "Bangladesh",
  "date": "11/10/2014",
  "id": 4482771
}, {
  "name": "Judith",
  "city": "Philippines",
  "date": "13/9/2015",
  "id": 4981921,

}, {
  "name": "Earl",
  "city": "Ukraine",
  "date": "21/6/2015",
  "id": 4024523,
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is watch a variable in scope (I use "search" below).

When it starts with "#", search only on that property. When it doesn't start with "#", search on all properties.

I've created a new array called "filteredUsers" because we don't want to modify the original "users" array.

To make things easier, we're using Angular's filter service (remember to include `$filter` in your controller).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("controller", function($scope, $filter) {

    var users = [{
      "name": "Bruce",
      "city": "Thailand",
      "date": "1/12/2014",
      "id": 3376848
    }, {
      "name": "Frank",
      "city": "Bangladesh",
      "date": "11/10/2014",
      "id": 4482771
    }, {
      "name": "Judith",
      "city": "Philippines",
      "date": "13/9/2015",
      "id": 4981921,

    }, {
      "name": "Earl",
      "city": "Ukraine",
      "date": "21/6/2015",
      "id": 4024523,
    }];

    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.filteredUsers = users;

    $scope.$watch("search", function(newVal, oldVal) {

      // if the search value starts with '#'
      if (newVal.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
        var searchProperty = newVal.substring(1, newVal.indexOf(":")); // string between '#' and first ':'
        var searchValue = $scope.search.substring(newVal.indexOf(":") + 1).trim(); // string after first ':'. will chuck some errors if there is no ':' but you can check this yourself

        // if there is both a property and value do the search on a single property
        if (searchProperty && searchValue) {
          // Angular's filter service requires an object (e.g. {name: "Bruce"}) but if we try {searchProperty: searchValue} it will filter on a property called "searchProperty" not the value of the variable so we create a new object and use that
          var searchObject = {};
          searchObject[searchProperty] = searchValue;
          
          $scope.filteredUsers = $filter('filter')(users, searchObject, false);
        } else {
          // Else show no users. It's up to you what you do here. You might want to show all users while the user is typing
          $scope.filteredUsers = [];
        }
      } else {
        // if the search value doesn't start with '#', use filter on the search value will look through all properties
        $scope.filteredUsers = $filter('filter')(users, newVal, false);
      }

    });

  });
```

```css
pre {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  Search:
  <input type="text" ng-model="search" />


  <h4>User</h4>
  <pre ng-repeat="user in filteredUsers">

    {{user | json}}

  </pre>

</div>
```